# phonegap, android, backbutton: can't make it work

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

Phonegap 1.8.1 -- Android API for 2.2 -- jQuery 1.7.1 -- jQueryMobile 1.0

I've made a very simple app to test this out and I just can't get it to work. Here it is.

INDEX.HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>TestApp</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile-1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function onDeviceReady() {

            document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackButton);
        }

        function onBackButton(e){
            console.log("C'mon guv! Gimme a chance!");
        }

        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    </script>
    <script type="test/javascript" src='cordova-1.8.1.js'></script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="homepage" data-role="page" data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Work with me here</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        I am page 1.
        <a href="#char-1" data-role="button">Next</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="char-1" data-role="page" data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="content">HAHAHA!</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="2" android:targetSdkVersion="14"/>
    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:anyDensity="true" />

    <application android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name="MyActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

ADDENDUM - I think the problem is that the 'deviceready' event either does not fire or fires before the code binds to the event. Not sure how to fix it.

Let me know if there's more information I need to provide.. I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm ashamed to admit this.

```
<script type="test/javascript" src='cordova-1.8.1.js'></script>
```

It's not test/javascript ... It's text/javascript.

:(

Comment: also it might have been loaded too late in timeline.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, back button press event is not working inside `onDeviceReady`. You have to trigger the event in the every page show. In my case, it works like this,

```
function onDeviceReady(){
    /*Back event handler for all pages navigation*/
    $(document).bind ('pageshow', function (e, data) {
        if ($.mobile.activePage.attr('id') == 'index') {
            document.addEventListener("backbutton", function () { 
                setTimeout( function() {navigator.app.exitApp();}, 100 );
            }, true);
        }
        else{
            document.addEventListener("backbutton", function () {
                setTimeout( function() {$.mobile.changePage("#index");}, 100 );
            }, true);
        }
    });


}
```

In my application, when you presses back button from first screen, it exits the application and if you presses inside any pages, it automatically comes to the first page.

Comment: <script type="test/javascript" src='cordova-1.8.1.js'></script> ? It's below the bit of code.

Comment: put it first before jquery js initialized in head tag.

Comment: How's this? https://gist.github.com/3129987 Still does not work for me... Am I missing something unrelated, a permission, something weird?